# Using Apache Cordova to browse TOR .onion urls

Tags: tor, apache-cordova

I would like to create a hybrid mobile application where I need to browse .onion urls and interact with servers on the Tor network.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I am aware of the [Guardian Project](https://github.com/guardianproject) but would love to know if there's already an out-of-the-box solution for [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/).

Any help would be appreciated.